# Unpredictable GameCenter Disconnection Errors [Sandbox]

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

I am developing a game with GameCenter, and I have several testers using it in an AdHoc (Beta) distribution, thus they are using Sandbox to test as we prepare to go live.

I am experiencing unpredictable disconnections from GameCenter. For example, when using `GKLeaderboard.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` to load the top leaderboard scores, it will return a `NSError` indicating that the player is not authenticated (error code `#6`, even though he was authenticated at the beginning of the session and previous requests of the same kind have succeeded). Sometimes this even happens at the end of a game, after successfully finishing a `GKTurnBasedMatch`, when I am attempting to report scores to the leaderboard.

A few things I've noticed:

1. It happens on my iPad frequently (several times per day) and to several of my beta testers, but it has never happened on my iPhone or to certain other beta testers, even when the players are playing at the same time. For example, I can play a game with my iPhone vs. my iPad, and the iPad will encounter this error quite consistently but the iPhone never will.
2. It seems to be worse sometimes than at other times. For example, I couldn't even play a single turn based match on Monday night, and my beta testers were having lots of problems then too, but it worked fine on Tuesday night.
3. It looks like there is no Authentication Changed message sent (i.e., the `setAuthenticateHandler` block is not called, nor is `GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName` posted). My first indication that something has gone wrong is simply the fact that a GameCenter request fails with an error.

The above make me **feel** like this is a problem with the Sandbox simply being unreliable (e.g., it was overloaded on Monday). However, I cannot risk this kind of experience in a live application.

So, my question is 2 part:

1. Can anybody confirm that GameCenter is actually reliable in Production, and that these problems are Sandbox only? Or at least confirm that the problem is not with my code?
2. How can I defensively code against these kind of errors? I've tried calling `[[GKPlayer localPlayer] setAuthenticateHandler:...]` when I encounter such an error, but it does not seem to re-authenticate the user.

Comment: I have seen similar behaviour in sandbox when spamming game center with requests. For example sending too many achievements, deleting/sending challenges, etc. In my experience it seems like an anti DoS attack mechanism, because it happens more often when you send game center requests in a row without waiting for the previous request to complete.I solved it by batching my requests and making sure previous requests were completed before sending new ones. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Dario that is very helpful, thanks. I had not considered that they might be rate limiting the client, and I definitely make a fair number of requests in succession.

Answer (score 0):

We're facing similiar problems. One reason might be, that GameCenter seems to run some keep-alive messaging on the main thread. Once your code is blocking this even shortly, you might get disconnected. Check your threads.

You might also consider this thread in the Apple Developer Forum:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/199452?tstart=0